# How do I change the default NLS parameters for date format through Toad?

Tags: oracle, tableau-api, date-formatting

I have a NLS date format as DD-MON-RR. This gives me the underlying date format as YY while I want to change it to YYYY. I tried using the following query and it ran successfully

```
DECLARE
       v_date DATE := sysdate;
BEGIN
       DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(TO_CHAR(v_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY'));
END;
```

But that didn't change the default format.

for some context, I am trying to import data from Oracle to Tableau. Unfortunately when I try to export a crosstab from Tableau server it looks at the underlying data rather than whats on the view. This causes the date that I have as  25-Jun-2017 to change to 25-Jun-17 in the excel.

The only workaround I have been able to understand is to change the default format of the underlying/source data which in this case is Oracle DB.

I am using TOAD and am trying to understand how can I change it to possibly DD/MON/RRRR format or something similar with 4 digits in the year column.

Any workaround is also appreciated

Comment: Does `alter session` not work? I imagine Toad has its own default in its preferences, but don't have a copy to find out exactly where. Not that you should really rely on NLS settings, can't you just use `to_char()` with an explicit format mask? (Also, does Tableau have to take the value as a string - can't it see the original date? Not sure what you mean by 'underlying data' here)

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you for your comments. I tried using to_date followed by to_char (since the field is already in date format). But unfortunately that doesn't work. I tried using alter session nls_date_format='DD/MON/RRRR' but its throwing an error. As for tableau, it takes it as a date not string, and the problem is it does see the original date in the original NLS format. And that's why it gives me the date format when downloaded in DD/MON/RR instead of DD/MON/RRRR. I hope that clarifies things

Comment: A date doesn't have any intrinsic format. Doing `to_date(to_char(...))` is not going to help you. You need to look at how Tableau is formatting the date it gets back, from what you've said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Manage your date format masking using the most reasonable approach**

First of all, I agree with Alex regarding using `to_char`.  This would be my first choice for modifying date masks for specific requirements.

In Toad on an ad hoc basis, you could just invoke the alter session command as needed:

`ALTER SESSION SET nls_date_format='DD/MON/RRRR';`

If you are partial to a specific date format mask (and you see yourself often issuing the command, `ALTER SESSION SET NLS...`) then perhaps you might want to consider changing your user login settings.

If you just modify your specific user preference login file, login.sql (see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQPUG/ch_two.htm#SQPUG337) ), your session will adhere to the date format mask of your choosing at the beginning of your session. I am partial to creating the environment variable, SQLPATH, and placing my login script there.

Toad will honor your login.sql file settings (e.g. see this [post](https://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-for-oracle/f/10/t/9887)).

Since this is driven by specific requirements or personal preferences, I would never think of modifying this from default at the site level.

Comment: I think (but I did not test) TOAD honors your login.sql file only if you run your code as script (e.i. hit "F5") but not when you execute a single statement by "F9" or "Ctrl+Enter"

Answer (score 4):

As already given in other answers you can set `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` by `ALTER SESSION`.

In order to set it only for you local PC, open Registry Editor and navigate to `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\KEY_%ORACLE_HOME_NAME%`, resp. `HKLM\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_%ORACLE_HOME_NAME%`.

There you can add a String Value `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`, for example:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_OraClient11g_home1]
"NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT"="YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SSfmXFF3"
"NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT"="YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SSfmXFF3 fmTZH:TZM"
"NLS_DATE_FORMAT"="YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\KEY_OraClient11g_home1]
"NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT"="YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SSfmXFF3"
"NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT"="YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SSfmXFF3 fmTZH:TZM"
"NLS_DATE_FORMAT"="YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS"
```

You can set `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` also as an Environment Variable in Windows Settings.

Answer (score 2):

`alter session set nls_date_format='DD/MON/RRRR'` programmatically in the application or

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_after_logon AFTER LOGON ON DATABASE
BEGIN
   execute immediate 'alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT=''DD/MON/RRRR''';
END;
```

in system or sys schema.

Alternatively, you may use

```
alter system set NLS_DATE_FORMAT='DD/MON/RRRR' scope = both
```

provided you're in system or sys, again.

Comment: Thank you!! I can't use the second one, but I want to use the first command. However, its giving me an error saying " missing or invalid option".

Comment: @AmitSinghParihar - the first statement is mssing the keyword `set`. The trigger seems like overkill, as different queries and users will want/need different formats; though as I mentioned, you shouldn't rely on NLS settings anyway... and some clients will override the trigger value too.