# Windows Server 2016 Passing Dates Differently to Oracle 64 bit Client

Tags: c#, oracle12c, windows-server-2016

I have an MVC application hosted on Windows Server 2016 that was using the 32 bit Oracle client to connect to a DB. I upgraded it to the 64 bit client.

The problem is that the server is now passing the dates in a different format to the DB. It passes it using C#:

```
comm.Parameters.Add(DATABASE_PARAMETERS.FIELDS.START_DATE, OracleDbType.Date).Value = startDate; //startDate is a DateTime variable
```

When that date hit the DB, it was coming in the format 'dd-MMM-yyyy'. Since switching to the 64 bit client, the date is showing up on the DB side as 'yy-mm-dd'.

So the format the server is passing the date as has changed, which causing errors on the DB. The DB contains hundreds of packages, so changing the DB code to reformat all the dates is not an option, I need to figure out how to get the server to pass them correctly again. It still works fine from my desktop using the exact same code, this is only a problem once deployed to the server.

I have tried changing the short date format in the region setting in the control panel. I have tried changing the short date value in the registry "HKEY_USERS -> .DEFAULT -> Control Panel -> International".

I have tried passing the date a formatted string instead of DateTime.

I have tried adding this code in the Global.asax.cs of the web project:

```
        protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo newCulture = (System.Globalization.CultureInfo)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
            newCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd-MMM-yyyy";
            newCulture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = "-";
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
        }
```

Nothing is working. The date is still showing up on the DB as 'yy-mm-dd'.

Any idea how I can fix this?

Edit: To add more to this, the error that is specifically being thrown is:

```
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
```

And is happening on a line in the DB:

```
l_end_date := '1-jan-2099';
```

So adding a format to this:

```
l_end_date := to_date('1jan2099', 'dd-mon-yyyy');
```

Solves that problem, but I cannot do this to every date variable across the entire system.

The question is why this executes no problem when I run it from my desktop, but causes an error when I run it from the server when they are running the exact same code and the same Oracle client? And why only once I switched to 64 bit Oracle?

I was saying the server is passing it differently because in the DB package, the first thing I try as a debugging step is to print the value of the In parameter.

When I print the variable as it's passed from my desktop, it's in the format 'dd-MMM-yyyy'. When I use the 32 bit client, it's the same. But when deployed to the server it's 'yy-mm-dd'.

So I think it's something on the server, because it works on my desktop, and with the 32 bit Oracle client.

Edit 2, here's some more code that's been asked for. Here's the C# function that calls the DB package:

```
        public CustomObject GetList(string username, DateTime? startDate, DateTime? endDate)
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (comm = new OracleCommand("db.funtion", conn))
            {
                comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                comm.Parameters.Add(TASConstants.DATABASE_PARAMETERS.FIELDS.BATCH_OUTPUT_CURSOR, OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.Output);
                comm.Parameters.Add(TASConstants.DATABASE_PARAMETERS.FIELDS.USER_NAME, OracleDbType.Varchar2, TASConstants.DATABASE_PARAMETERS.LENGTHS.USER_NAME).Value = username;
                comm.Parameters.Add(TASConstants.DATABASE_PARAMETERS.FIELDS.START_DATE, OracleDbType.Date).Value = startDate;
                comm.Parameters.Add(TASConstants.DATABASE_PARAMETERS.FIELDS.END_DATE, OracleDbType.Date).Value = endDate;
                comm.Parameters.Add(TASConstants.DATABASE_PARAMETERS.FIELDS.MESSAGE_FLAG, OracleDbType.Varchar2, TASConstants.DATABASE_PARAMETERS.LENGTHS.MESSAGE_FLAG);
                comm.Parameters[TASConstants.DATABASE_PARAMETERS.FIELDS.MESSAGE_FLAG].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                comm.Parameters.Add(TASConstants.DATABASE_PARAMETERS.FIELDS.MESSAGE_BODY, OracleDbType.Varchar2, TASConstants.DATABASE_PARAMETERS.LENGTHS.MESSAGE_BODY);
                comm.Parameters[TASConstants.DATABASE_PARAMETERS.FIELDS.MESSAGE_BODY].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(comm);
                DataTable result = new DataTable();
                BatchList batchList = new BatchList();

                try
                {
                    da.Fill(result); //error throw here
```

The DB package

```
  Procedure function(p_ssp_rec_refcur  Out ssp_rec_refcur
                            ,p_username        In Varchar2
                            ,p_start_date      In Date
                            ,p_end_date        In Date
                            ,p_successful_flag Out Varchar2
                            ,p_message         Out Varchar2) As
    
    l_start_date Date := p_start_date;
    l_end_date   Date := p_end_date;
  Begin
    If Not ws_base.authenticate_fn(p_username, 8013, ws_base.c_update, p_message) Then
      Return;
    End If;If p_end_date Is Null Then
      l_end_date := '1-jan-2099'; --error thrown here
    End If;
  
    If p_start_date Is Null Then
      l_start_date := '1-jan-1901'; 
    End If;
```

So yes, adding a date format to the line for l_end_date solves the issue, but management will not accept that solution because 1) it worked with the 32 bit Oracle client, and 2) it works with the 64 bit client from our desktops. Same code, same client installed.

The mystery here is why that is the case?

Comment: @J.Cart dates have no format. They are binary values. It's not the server, it's not the client. Formats apply only when parsing strings into dates, or when dates are formatted as strings. This means *your code* is sending the dates as strings instead of actual date parameters. One way or another, you're either constructing SQL queries by concatenating values, or converting dates to strings before executing a query

Comment: @J.Cart btw this means that your code is vulnerable to SQL injection too

Comment: Then why does it work fine on 1 machine but fails on another, when using the same code against the same DB? The only thing changing is the machine it's on. And worked on the failing machine with the old client. The date being passed in is DateTime, not being cast to a string, and parameter on the DB side is a Date.

Comment: Were I a gambling man, in the absence of a reproducible example, I'd wager that you had set a non-default `nls_date_format` when configuring the previous Oracle client while you're running with the default setup on the new client.  That setting controls how Oracle does implicit string to date (and date to string) conversion.  It would be better to not rely on implicit conversions but that would require code changes.

Comment: @JustinCave Yes as mentioned above using an explicit date format solves the issue, but is not feasible for the amount of code that's affected. How do I configure 'nls_date_format' on the new client?

Comment: OK so that code sample is helpful since it clearly shows the issue is _not_ in the passing of the date from the client - it is a bug **in the function**.

Comment: You can set `nls_date_format` as an environment variable or you should be able to set it in the registry.  I think hklm\software\oracle\key_OracleHome would be the right place.  It would be a code change, but hopefully a small one, to add an explicit `alter session set nls_date_format` after you've connected to the database so that the application doesn't depend on client settings.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#sthref364 Rather than `l_end_date := '1-jan-2099';` have you tried `l_end_date := DATE '2009-01-01';` as per the docs?

Comment: "`l_end_date := to_date('1jan2099', 'dd-mon-yyyy');` Solves that problem (...)" -- and is the **right** thing to do here...

Comment: @stickybit Yes, it is the right way. However due to reasons above my head, is not the way. As mentioned this only happens on 1 machine, and I'm trying to find out why.

Comment: @J.Cart Did you try using date literals like I suggested? There is no benefit to the code, as is, vs date literals. Fixing anything _other than that function_ is a band-aid. Fix the real problem. There is no point listening to someone who tells you that the function is correct. **Clearly it isn't, since it isn't working for you**. Point them to the docs if they don't understand how dates in databases work.

Comment: @mjwills Yes it did work, as did adding an explicit format to the date. I know that's the right solution, but not the task at hand unfortunately

Comment: @J.Cart Why do you not want to apply the proper reliable fix? And, if you don't want to (which is weird, but OK) - did you try Justin's `alter session set nls_date_format` idea?

Comment: To be clear though - whomever is writing those functions that way needs to be told to stop doing that. It is wrong.

Comment: @J.Cart: You're concentrating to cure the symptoms instead of the underlying disease. Explain to those "above your head" that this problems will reoccur over and over again if not fixed *properly*. Which in turn means investing man power and in the end money over and over again with no end.

Comment: @mjwills What I want to do has nothing to do with it lol, otherwise this would be fixed. Yes alter session set nls_date_format works as well, but they do not want to change the DB, they want to know why this issue only occurs from 1 server.

Comment: Perhaps also update the question to reflect our current understanding. `Windows Server 2016 Passing Dates Differently to Oracle 64 bit Client` isn't right - since it isn't a date _passing_ issue it is a date _parsing_ issue.

Comment: @J.Cart - Note that `alter session` is not changing the DB.  It's just making explicit a session-level setting that is controlled by the client machine creating the session.  If the application has a dependency on session-level settings, it makes sense for the application to explicitly set up its environment rather than hoping that the client has implicitly set it up the way the application desires.  Otherwise, you've got an application with relatively undocumented dependencies on client-level settings that will cause frustration whenever it gets deployed to a new machine.

Comment: `but management will not accept that solution because 1) it worked with the 32 bit Oracle client, and 2) it works with the 64 bit client from our desktops.` As a general rule you should be _educating_ management, not letting them make technical decisions (which is generally bad since they are the _least_ well informed about the technical details).

Comment: @J.Cart `l_end_date := '1-jan-2099'` that's your bug. This has nothing to do with the client, the OS or even the rest of the stored procedure. You're trying to assign a localized string to a date parameter. Don't do that, ever. `to_date('1jan2099', 'dd-mon-yyyy');` just covers up the bug. The Oracle [Date Literals docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#BABGIGCJ) show the correct syntax is `DATE '2099-01-01'`. Forget about the non-default "default" format that changes on every machine or even with a setting.

Comment: @J.Cart `but management will not accept that solution because 1) it worked with the 32 bit Oracle client, and 2) it works with the 64 bit client from our desktops.` no it doesn't work. A single setting change will cause the same problems there. That's 100% bad code. They can't make it "good" just because they said so any more than they can make the Earth flat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue does not appear to be related to how the application passes in dates.  The issue appears to be that the stored procedures the application uses are written incorrectly (or at least poorly) and depend on the client's `nls_date_format` being set to a particular value in order to function correctly.  That means that the same code running on different machines (or using a different client on the same machine depending on how the client chooses to set the `nls_date_format`) will behave differently.  Obviously, that isn't a desirable property for an application to have.

Options to fix the problem in order of correctness (I understand that you're probably limited to some of the more band-aid-ish approaches right now)

**Fix the stored procedures to use proper date literals or explicit `to_date` conversions.**

If the procedure used date literals or explicit `to_date` calls, it would work regardless of the client settings

```
If p_end_date Is Null Then
  l_end_date := date '2099-01-01'; 
End If;
  
If p_start_date Is Null Then
  l_start_date := to_date( '1-jan-1901', 'dd-mon-yyyy' ); 
End If;
```

**Explicitly set the `nls_date_format` on login**

After creating a database connection, you can set the `nls_date_format`

```
alter session set nls_date_format = dd-mon-yyyy
```

That at least ensures that the application's code base is setting up the environment that it specifically needs so that when the code base gets moved to a different machine it will work correctly.

**Set the `nls_date_format` as an environment variable on the client**

On the client, you can set an environment variable for `nls_date_format`.  You're still dependent on client settings but at least this is a machine-level client setting.

**Set the `nls_date_format` in the registry for the particular Oracle client installation**

You can set the `nls_date_format` in the registry for the particular Oracle client installation that you're using.  Here's [another StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45028074/10397) that goes into a bit more detail on doing this.  This means, though, that if you try to use a different Oracle client on the same machine that you'd get failures again and future you would have to remember that you modified the registry to get the app to work previously.

```
hklm\software\oracle\key_OracleHome
```

Comment: I tried setting the environment variable NLS_DATE_FORMAT to DD-MM-YYYY. If I do echo %nls_date_format% from the command line it shows the correct format. Still shows on the DB as yy-mm-dd. I also tried changing the registry values as described in the link above and it did not work

Comment: I should clarify as everyone is pointing to the explicit date format as the best fix that it is only 1 example out of dozens where this is causing a problem. There is another package where the line "l_new_date Date := p_start_date" throws an error. And another where passing the date parameter to another function within the package throws an error. Those dates do have explicit formats

Comment: I am going to accept this answer and just tell them they need to fix their code or it will not work

Comment: @J.Cart - Note that it appears the code expects the session's `nls_date_format` to be dd-mon-yyyy not dd-mm-yyyy.  What do you mean by "shows on the DB"?  Are you querying the database's `nls_date_format` or your session's `nls_date_format'?

Comment: In the package, the first thing I'm doing is writing the variable p_start_date to a table. It is showing as 1-DEC-2020 when the package is called from the app on my desktop, and 20-12-01 when the app is called from the server